# Performing operations on multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am busy with a project that will need to perform tasks on a large number of dataframes which have been read in from csv files. This will need to happen one row at a time, one dataframe at a time.

So the idea is that I select the first row from the first dataframe and do something with that data. I then move on to the first row from the second dataframe and once again do the same thing with that data. Once i've gone through every dataframe, I then go back to the first dataframe and select the second row of data. I continue doing this until i've gone through every row of every dataframe.

I will need to know which dataframe im working with at any point in time. So when I select a row from a df, I will need to also identify which df it is.

My question is around what datastructure to use to accomplish this. I was wondering if I could use a dict:

```
dict_of_dataframes = {'abc' = df1, 'xyz' = df2}
```

There will be over 100 dataframes, and each dataframe may have hundreds/thousands of rows.

Is a dict a good way to go to accomplish this?

---

A bit more clarification on the requirement:

Each dataframe is created from a csv containing historical stock data, ie:

```
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
```

There is one csv / dataframe for every stock. Each line of the csv / dataframe is one day, going back several years.

The goal is to backtest various portfolio strategies on the data (NB: This is not to test a strategy on one stock,...it is to test the entire portfolio of stocks). To do this there must be no ability to look ahead. In other words I need to go through one day at a time for every stock, then move to the next day.

So I can't just finish one dataframe by itself and then move to the next. I need to see how the portfolio as a whole performs through time.

I hope that helps clarify?

Comment: Why do you need to operate a row at a time, what's the constraint? You could consider a panel but a dict would work fine

Comment: I am not familiar with a Panel but will look into it. The reason for one row at a time is that this is to backtest stock market data over many different stock symbols. It would test one day at a time, one stock at a time. In other words it needs to simulate the passage of time throughout every stock, not just skip to the end of one stock and then do the next one. If you can suggest a better way to do this I will be happy to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to flesh out the details in your question but a Panel may suit what you want

Comment: I wouldn't recommend panels here. Panels are great for frames that share index and columns (which doesn't seem to be the case for you). Speaking about your problem: You are kind of rearranging a time series to make it into a dataframe such that a row is day and the columns are something else (like 5min stamps?). PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS. You can do all the subsampling later. One stock is one time series is one column of a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated the original question to clarify.

Comment: Index shared is date. Columns shared are Open, High, , Low and Close (+ Volume?). When you import data for multiple stocks in Pandas via the DataReader, it puts the data into a panel. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you can put all files in one dataframe adding an extra field for the stock, sort it by date and stock and iterate over the rows. I think this fits your purpose.